# Doctrine Entity Manager gets Read Only error from database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.2

```
public function save($itemId, $invoiceName)
{
    $query = "
           INSERT INTO invoice (item_id, invoice_name)
           VALUES (" . $itemId . ",'" . $invoiceName . ")
    ";
    $connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection('master');
    return $connection->executeQuery($query);
}
```

Error while trying to insert into table:

```
An exception occurred while executing ' INSERT INTO invoice (item_id, invoice_name) VALUES (10600029,'FV/1823/06/2018/SOL') ': SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1290 The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Checked connection to DB its fine.
Tried to save something with same user with a DBeaver DB client and it went through all fine - saved without any problem.

Comment: you may check your MySQL user permission.

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the connection used before to change connection and insert I think, try something like this:

```
$connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->close();

$query = "
       INSERT INTO invoice (item_id, invoice_name)
       VALUES (" . $itemId . ",'" . $invoiceName . ")
";
$connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection('master');
return $connection->executeQuery($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even tho I specified 'master' the request was catched by slave all the time.

```
$entityManager->getConnection()->prepare('INSERT ... ')->execute();
```

Appeared to fix the problem.